# Prevent the scrollbar (overflow) from appearing because of a Navbar

Tags: jquery, html, css, resize, overflow

I'm building a website with a Navbar always present on the right side of the screen.

It has a fixed size and is collapsable before a certain screen width.

With overflow:hidden I was able to do what I want when the bar is collapsable but when the size is fixed I cant figure it out.

Here is some of the code:

```
#HTML
<nav>
    <ul class="links-to-floor">
        <li class="navCollapsed  navButton"><img src="img/feed_.png" alt="menu" /></li>
        <li class="list navButton"><a>Home</a></li>
        <li class="list navButton"><a>About me</a></li>
        <li class="list navButton"><a>Path</a></li>
        <li class="list navButton"><a>Skills</a></li>
        <li class="list navButton"><a>Portfolio</a></li>
        <li class="list navButton"><a>Contacts</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>


#CSS 
ul {
    list-style: none;
}

li a {
    min-height:50px;
    min-width:50px;
    padding-top:40%;
    padding-bottom:40%;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    color: white;
    background-color:#222222;
    font-size:0.8em;
    display:inline-block;
}

.list{
    display:none;
}

.navCollapsed {
    min-height:50px;
    min-width:50px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color:#303030;
}

.navCollapsed img{
    width:100%;
}

li a:hover{
    cursor:pointer;
    background:#fefefe;
}

.links-to-floor{
    min-width:60px;
    padding-top:5px;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    text-align:center;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
    overflow:hidden;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 780px) {

    .links-to-floor{
        right:5px;
        display:block;
        top:50%;
        margin-top:-257px;
        width:90px;
    }

    .list {
        display:inline-block;
    }

    li a {
        display:inline-block;
        padding-bottom:35px;
        padding-top:35px;
        width:80px;
        height:80px;
        line-height:10px;
    }

    .navCollapsed {
        display:none;
        width:80px;
        height:80px;
    }

}

#JS

$(window).resize(function(){
    setNavBar();
});

$(window).load(function(){
    setNavBar();
});

$('.navCollapsed').on('click', function() {
    if($('.list').is(':visible')){
        $('.list').hide();
        $('.links-to-floor').css('height', 'auto');
    } else {
        $('.list').css('display', 'inline-block');
        $('.links-to-floor').css('height', '100%');
    }
});

function setNavBar(){
    if (window.innerWidth >= 780) {
        $('.links-to-floor').css('width', '90px');
        $('.links-to-floor').css('height', 'auto');
        $('li a').css('width', '80px');
        $('li a').css('height', '80px');
        $('.navCollapsed').css('width', '80px');
        $('.navCollapsed').css('height', '80px');

    } else {
        $('.links-to-floor').css('width', (((window.innerHeight-(8*5))/7)+10)+'px');
        $('li a').css('width', (((window.innerHeight-(8*5))/7))+'px');
        $('li a').css('height', (((window.innerHeight-(8*5))/7))+'px');
        $('.navCollapsed').css('width', (((window.innerHeight-(8*5))/7))+'px');
        $('.navCollapsed').css('height', (((window.innerHeight-(8*5))/7))+'px');
    }
}
```

You can see whats happening here: [filipesousacardoso.github.io](http://filipesousacardoso.github.io)

Comment: First of all you have only one div to scroll all others are commented out. Secondly why are all your divs positioned absolute? Maybe you want them stacked ? And you want the scrollbar or don't?

Comment: I commented eveything because the problem isnt there. At least not this problem..
I'm using ascensor.js and I dont want the scrollbar to appear ever.
When I resize the window it appears, because of the navbar. I managed to make it go away when the window width is less than 780px putting overflow:hidden in the .links-to-floor class but it does not work if the width is larger than that